# Counting occurrences of multiple characters in a string, with python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to create a function that -given a string- will return the count of non-allowed characters ('error_char'), like so: 'total count of not-allowed / total length of string'.

So far I've tried:

```
def allowed_characters(s):
    s = s.lower()
    correct_char = 'abcdef'
    error_char = 'ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    counter = 0
    
    for i in s:
        if i in correct_char:
            no_error = '0'+'/'+ str(len(s))
            return no_error
    
        elif i in error_char: 
            counter += 1
            result = str(sum(counter)) + '/' + str(len(s))
            return result
```

but all I get is '0/56' where I'm expecting '22/56' since m,x,y,z are 'not allowed' and m repeats 19 times

```
allowed_characters('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmxyz')
'0/56'
```

Then I've tried:

```
def allowed_characters(s):
    s = s.lower()
    correct_char = 'abcdef'
    error_char = 'ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    counter = 0
    
    for i in s:
        if i in correct_char:
            no_error = '0'+'/'+ str(len(s))
            return no_error
    
        elif i in error_char: 
            import regex as re
            rgx_pattern = re.compile([error_char])
            count_e = rgx_pattern.findall(error_char, s)
            p_error = sum([count_e.count(i) for i in error_char])
            result = str(p_error) + '/' + str(len(s))
```

But I get the same result...

I've also tried these other ways, but keep getting the same:

```
def allowed_characters1(s):
    s = s.lower()
    correct_char = 'abcdef'
    
    for i in s:
        if i not in correct_char:
            counter = sum([s.count(i) for i in s])
            p_error = str(counter) + '/' + str(len(s))
            return p_error
            
        elif i in correct_char:
            no_error = '0'+'/'+ str(len(s))
            return no_error
```

and...

```
def allowed_characters2(s):
    s = s.lower()
    correct_char = 'abcdef'
    
    for i in s:
        if i not in correct_char:
            counter = sum(s.count(i))
            p_error = str(counter) + '/' + str(len(s))
            return p_error
            
        elif i in correct_char:
            no_error = '0'+'/'+ str(len(s))
            return no_error
```

I've even tried changing the logic and iterating over 'correct/error_char' instead, but nothing seems to work... I keep getting the same result over and over. It looks as though the loop stops right after first character or doesn't run the 'elif' part?

Comment: You always `return` immediately after seeing one character of your input, in all your attempted solutions.

Comment: @DanielHao ,  for the sample input I'd expect '3/56' ...but instead I get '0/56'

Comment: @DanielHao ,  for the sample input I'd expect '3/56' since x,y and z are 'not allowed' characters...but instead I get '0/56'

Comment: @DanielHao sorry for my late edit!

Comment: But there are more error_char in your input?  Eg. m? not only x, y,z?

Comment: @DanielHao yes, my apologies! so, allowed characters from a to f and not allowed characters from g to z

Comment: See the posts for your new Problem Desc. Let's chat - if you have further questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246521/discussion-between-daniel-hao-and-vanessa-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever it comes to do quicker *counting* - it's always good to think about *Counter*  You can try to simplify your code like this:

**Notes** - please don't change your Problem Description during the middle of people's answering posts.  That make it very hard to keep in-sync.

There is still room to improve it though.

```
from collections import Counter

def allowed_char(s):
    s = s.lower()
    correct_char = 'abcdef'
    error_char = 'ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    
  
    ok_counts = Counter(s)
    print(f' allowed: {ok_counts} ')
    correct_count  = sum(count for c, count in ok_counts.items() if c in correct_char)

    error_count = sum(count for c, count in ok_counts.items() if c in error_char)
   
    #return sum(not_ok.values()) / total

    return correct_count, error_count  # print both 
    

s =('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmxyz')

print(allowed_char(s))             # (34, 22)

print(allowed_char('abdmmmmxyz'))  # (3, 7)
```

Alternatively, you really want to use *for-loop* and learn to process the string of characters, you could try this:

```
def loop_count(s):
    s = s.lower()
    correct_count = error_count = 0

    for c in s:
        if c in correct_char:
            correct_count += 1
        else:
            error_count += 1

    return correct_count, error_count
```

Comment: @Vanessa_C try to see 2nd approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex replacement trick here using `len()`:

```py
def allowed_characters(s):
    return len(s) - len(re.sub(r'[^ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]+', '', s))
```

The above returns the length of the input string minus the length of the input with all allowed characters removed (alternatively minus the length of the string with only non allowed characters).